# Is it better to use local variables or chain methods inline?

Tags: java, coding-style

If I have a series of method invocations, the value of each used for the next call, should I store them in local variables, like so:

```
DynamicForm filledForm = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
String shareIdStr = filledForm.get("data[shareId]");
UUID shareId = UUID.fromString(shareIdStr);
Share share = Share.find.byId(shareId);
```

or as a single invocation chain, like so:

```
Share share = Share.find.byId(UUID.fromString(Form.form().bindFromRequest().get("data[shareId]")));
```

In this case, the only value that is used again is `share`. Perhaps the answer is somewhere in-between, or is something completely different. What's your opinion?

Comment: Obviously there's no single "right" answer.

Comment: I guess if you reuse the local variables, store them. Otherwise decide whether your code is readable enough with chain method invocation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Not chaining Methods :**

ADV

1. Enhances readability.
2. Gives an opportunity for re-usage.
3. Pin pointing exceptions (if any) becomes easier.
4. Debugging becomes easier, i.e. setting breakpoints on specific invocation is easy.

DisADV

1. Increases length( I wont say size :) ) of code.
2. IDE warnings (if any).

> **Chaining Methods**

ADV

1. Reduces the need for creating multiple temp. variables.
2. Is a [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)
3. Reduces the number of lines to be written.

DisADV

1. Reduces readability of code.
2. Commenting becomes difficult (if any) for particular methods called.
3. Debugging the whole chain of invocation becomes very difficult.

Comment: Method chaining can also be a pain in debugging (e.g. can't set a breakpoint on a specific invocation in the middle of the chain)

Comment: @Durandal You are right! I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

The first way is only useful if you re-use these variables later in the method. If not, Eclipse  will tell you they are not used. So the second way is better, I think.

To clarify a long line of code, I like to write it like this :

```
Share share = Share.find
                   .byId(UUID.fromString(Form.form()
                                             .bindFromRequest()
                                             .get("data[shareId]")                                   
                                         )
                   );
```

Comment: Its worth noting eclipse won't complain for the first example since each variable is used once

Comment: @RichardTingle You're right but what's the point of storing an object you will only refer once the line after and never after that

Answer (score 2):

You can only compare these two forms if you consider you will not reuse variables. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to compare them.

Generally the first variant gives your code more readability and potentially makes it easier to maintain.

Personally I develop a lot for embedded systems where the target platform has big constraints on computation power and size. Therefore I typically inline the code, so that my bytecode is smaller.

If I am to develop an application to run on a powerful server, or even the regular PC, then I would most likely opt for variant one.

Comment: In most of the cases compiler will optimize for you. You don't need to do it intentionally right.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to read your code. Local variables are useful if you are going to use them again. Otherwise proceed with chain invocation.