# Java.util.Scanner, issue with closing

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Okay so the issue with this code is that if it iterates over the loop more than once, having closed the Scanner causes the code to neglect to scan for further user input. I understand that the problem has to be an internal one within the Scanner class but does anyone have a way I can close the Scanner in a safer way? (It might help to copy the code and try entering "55" or "j" for example if you don't realize the issue I'm having right away).

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int numCom = 0, count = 0;
    boolean valid = false;

    do{
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            if(count == 0){
                System.out.println("Okay, how many adversaries would you like to be put up against? (between 1-8)");
                count++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error!\nPlease enter a number between 1-8.");
            }
            numCom = num.nextInt();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        if(numCom < 9 && numCom > 0){
            valid = true;
        }
        num.close();
    }while(!valid);
}//main()
```

Comment: You commented on all the answers except mine. Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really been on this site for a while (been smooth sailing recently). I've gone away from attempting to close the Scanners at all for stuff like this as it also closes the input stream (System.in for this case). If there's a way to reopen the stream afterwards that would be fine.

Comment: I already answered all of that...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to ensure that only your scanner is closed and not the System.in. Calling scanner.close() in turn calls the close on the source you provide in the constructor (System.in) in this case. You have two options. The more elegant one would be to use
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html

```
Scanner num = new Scanner(new CloseShieldInputStream(System.in));
```

a pure java solution would be

```
public class Scan {
private static final class MyShieldedSystemIn extends InputStream {
    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        return System.in.read(b);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        return System.in.read(b, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // do nothing
        System.out.println("ignoring call to close()");
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return System.in.read();
    }
}
final static InputStream SSI = new MyShieldedSystemIn();
public static void main(String[] args){
    int numCom = 0, count = 0;
    boolean valid = false;


    do{
        Scanner num = new Scanner(SSI);
        try{
            if(count == 0){
                System.out.println("Okay, how many adversaries would you like to be put up against? (between 1-8)");
                count++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error!\nPlease enter a number between 1-8.");
            }
            numCom = num.nextInt();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        if(numCom < 9 && numCom > 0){
            valid = true;
        }
        num.close();
    }while(!valid);
}//main()
```

}

Comment: This is a solid tip but since it unfortunately does not have a counterpart in java it's just more going into my code at the end of the day.

Comment: Honestly, just to add one thing, this was also the most well-informed post on here so good on you man (or woman, idk)! :)

Comment: This is a lot of unnecessary code. You don't ***need*** to close the Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Create and close the scanner outside of the loop. Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numCom = 0, count = 0;
        boolean valid = false;
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            try {
                if (count == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Okay, how many adversaries would you like to be put up against? (between 1-8)");
                    count++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error!\nPlease enter a number between 1-8.");
                }
                numCom = num.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            if (numCom < 9 && numCom > 0) {
                valid = true;
            }
        } while (!valid);
        num.close();
    } //main()
```

Comment: No good, try it out but enter a value that causes the loop to go through more than once. This was my first instinct but it doesn't even work right if you don't close the Scanner, try it out

Comment: Have you tried making a function of the code instead of having it in your main?

Comment: Yeah, I just copy/pasted this out into a temp class actually; in my full program it is a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS : java 7+ http://ideone.com/dxtXmz

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    int numCom = 0, count = 0;
    boolean valid = false;
        try (Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            do{
                try{
                    if(count == 0){
                        System.out.println("Okay, how many adversaries would you like to be put up against? (between 1-8)");
                        count++;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Error!\nPlease enter a number between 1-8.");
                    }
                    numCom = num.nextInt();
                }catch(Exception e){}
                if(numCom < 9 && numCom > 0){
                    valid = true;
                }
            }while(!valid);
        }
}//main()
```

**OR**

TRY THIS : http://ideone.com/LaN6kF

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int numCom = 0, count = 0;
boolean valid = false;

    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
    try{
        if(count == 0){
            System.out.println("Okay, how many adversaries would you like to be put up against? (between 1-8)");
            count++;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error!\nPlease enter a number between 1-8.");
        }
        numCom = num.nextInt();
    }catch(Exception e){}
    if(numCom < 9 && numCom > 0){
        valid = true;
    }
}while(!valid);

    num.close();
}//main()
```

Basically the resource : scanner : is allocated only once and reused.
and when not required, its closed.

Comment: Just double-checked it out once more (I've been stuck with this problem for a while and moved on until now) and yes it works with any variety of numbers. Enter a string as input and boom, down goes the program..

Comment: @EricLeFort well that's another question. You're handling your input with `nextInt()` and therefore you cannot read input other than ints. Try `ReadLine()` for strings.

Comment: Well I understand that, that's why I have the try-catch block in the first place. The user however likes to destroy things and I want to be able to handle any input. Robust code is good code!

Comment: Are you talking about the try(resource){} one? That wasn't giving me any luck either

Comment: see the new answer i added

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to handle Strings as well, try this one :** http://ideone.com/f7IMwD

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numCom = 0, count = 0;
        boolean valid = false;
        try (Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            do {
                try {
                    if (count == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Okay, how many adversaries would you like to be put up against? (between 1-8)");
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error!\nPlease enter a number between 1-8.");
                    }
                    String line = num.nextLine();
                    numCom = Integer.parseInt(line);
                    if (numCom < 9 && numCom > 0) {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    valid = false;
                }

            } while (!valid);
        }
    }//main()
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks like it might actually have potential. Just wish there was a way that wasn't so tedious you know? Edit: this works just fine, would upvote you if I could!

Comment: Leaving `catch` blocks empty and hoping `exceptions` will be taken care of *automatically* - might sound like less *tedious* but not what should be done.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't even talking about the catch block, just having to instantiate a new String and then using the parseInt() method. You could still leave the catch block blank without any repercussions!

Comment: you can reduce this code by method chaining. but do read my answer about it here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24632141/3603806

Answer (score 0):

When you close a `Scanner`, it will close its input source, which in this case is `System.in`. Once you've closed `System.in`, you cannot read input any more. Do not close the `Scanner`. It does not have any resources that need to be closed, unless you want to close the input source, which in this case you don't. If you remove the `num.close();` call, your code will work correctly.

Edit: Still, you're making heavy work of it. Your code's length could be *halved* with no loss of functionality:

```
int numAdversaries;
System.out.println("Okay, how many adversaries would you like to be put up against? (between 1-8)");
for (;;) {
    try {
        numAdversaries = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        if (numAdversaries >= 1 && numAdversaries <= 8) break;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    System.out.println("Error!\nPlease enter a number between 1-8.");
}
```